# Euler Equation with a certain type of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the Euler equation in the following form

$$x^2h''(x)+xh'(x)=b^2h(x)$$

with the condition $h(a)=0$. The general solution to this equation is

$$h(x)=c_1x^{b}+c_2x^{-b}$$

Now, my question is how to utilize this given condition to the get the solution in the following form

$$h(x)=c_0\left\{\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)^{b}-\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)^{-b}\right\}$$

Comment: Just put $$
c_{\,1}  = {{c_{\,0} } \over {a^{\,b} }}\;\quad c_{\,2}  = {{c_{\,0} } \over {a^{\, - b} }}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c_1 a^b + c_2 a^{-b} = 0$, then $c_2 = \ldots$.  Now see what $c_0$ has to be to put the solution in the desired form.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from @Robert Israel and @G Cab,
\begin{align}
&c_1a^b+c_2a^{-b}=0\\
&\Rightarrow c_1a^b=-c_2a^{-b}\\
&\mbox{Let}\,\,\,\,c_1a^b=-c_2a^{-b}=c_0\\
&\Rightarrow c_1=\frac{c_0}{a^b}\\
&\Rightarrow c_2=-\frac{c_0}{a^{-b}}\\
\end{align}

Thanks guyz!